# I am working on spring MVC and need help setting flag

Tags: java, spring, rest

This is the source code i have

```
public Customer add(UI uI)
    {

        String url = "https://localhost:8080/api; 
        System.out.println("url is "+url);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Customer customer = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Customer.class);
        System.out.println(customer);
        customerDao.save(customer);
        return customer;

    }
```

I receive this JSON data from localhost api as response

```
{"id":"12","datetime":"08:39:02","status":good,"first_name":"ABC","last_name":"xyz"}
```

for status i have two values good and bad and my question is how can i raise a flag if the status is bad.

Comment: what do you meant by raise a flag?

Comment: if it is bad then set value of the variable as somthing and call a different function

Comment: why didn't you use `boolean` instead of `String`?

Comment: Again. You should be clear on what you want. Set value  of which variable of which class and call which function

Comment: if it is bad i want to call inspectCustomer function

Comment: you can the status of your response if 200 then it is success else 400 or 500 means error and exicute your function respectively

Comment: If you are keen about the JSON response, then receive it as a JSONObject and iterate it to the required field to check. In your case, the status is inside the Json, so you have to deal it as a json and validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    JSOnObject resp = `{"id":"12","datetime":"08:39:02","status":good,"first_name":"ABC","last_name":"xyz"}`;
String status = resp.getAsString("status");
if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("good")){
  //set Flag
}

if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("bad")){
  //call function
}
```